# Solving integral with complex path integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Dear math stackexchange,

I'm trying to show this:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx = \frac{\pi}{\sin{(a\pi)}}, 0<a<1$$

I tried:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =   \lim_{R\to\infty } \int_{-R}^{R} f(x) dx = \lim_{R\to\infty } \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx$$

Then i want to split the integration on the boundaries of a rectangle defined by the vertices: 
$$ z = \pm R, z = \pm R + 2 \pi i $$

This is obviously $ z \in \mathbb{C}$ so i need to expand on a complex function that covers the real of the normal function. Maybe just: $\frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}$

Now i should just have to solve 4 path integrals, However they are quite difficult i think so i think i am on wrong path (No pun intended).

I would love some hints and tips to go about this problem

Comment: No, this is the right path for this problem. A circular arc would be much harder to deal with. Recall that there are infinitely many poles on the imaginary axis.

Comment: If you're interested in a different strategy, convert it to a Beta integral with $u=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the thing about those path integrals - the reason you chose that path - is that some will tend to variations on the integral we want to evaluate, and the others will go to zero. That is how we use the residue theorem to evaluate integrals; we don't start with a closed path, so we come back around to close it with pieces we can understand.

- $\int_{-R}^R$ : This is simple - it goes to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$, the integral we want to evaluate.
- $\int_{R}^{R+2\pi i}$ : $\dfrac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} = \dfrac{e^{(a-1)x}}{1+e^{-x}}$. When the real part of $z$ is $R$ and $s$ is real, $|e^{sx}|=e^{sR}$. Applied here,
  $$\left|\frac{e^{(a-1)x}}{1+e^{-x}}\right| = \frac{e^{(a-1)R}}{|1+e^{-x}|} \le \frac{e^{(a-1)R}}{1-e^{-R}}\to 0$$
  Integrate that along a path of fixed length $2\pi i$, and it goes to zero.
- $\int_{R+2\pi i}^{-R+2\pi i}$ : For this, we use the identity $f(x+2\pi i) = e^{2\pi i a}f(x)$; the translation leaves the denominator unchanged, and multiplies the numerator by a fixed quantity. Since we trace this integral backwards, there's an extra $-1$ factor, and this one tends to $-e^{2\pi i a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$.
- $\int_{-R+2\pi i}^{-R}$ : On this vertical segment, it's the $1$ term in the denominator that dominates. We get
  $$\left|\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}\right| = \frac{e^{-aR}}{|1+e^x|}\le\frac{e^{-aR}}{1-e^{-R}}\to 0$$
  Integrate that along a path of fixed length $2\pi$, and it goes to zero.

Adding up the pieces, we get a limit that's a sum of two constant multiples of the integral we're trying to evaluate. In order to solve for that integral, we need a second evaluation of the contour integral - and that calls for the residue theorem. There's exactly one pole in the rectangle enclosed, at $\pi i$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Jmerry thank you so much for providing such an in depth answer. I understand the method now and i'm trying to follow along. I really appreciate your help. But how come $f(x+2 \pi i ) =f(x) e^{2 \pi i a} $ ?

I am getting: $f(x+2 \pi i ) = \frac{e^{ax}e^{2 \pi i}}{1+e^{x}e^{2 \pi i}} $

Comment: That's not correct in the numerator - recall that the $+2\pi i$ gets multiplied by $a$ too. In the denominator - what's $e^{2\pi i}$?

Comment: Off course! $e^{2 \pi i}$ is just $1$. And i see my mistake in the denominator. So with your help i can just find the residue, set it equal to the remaining two integrals, use the $f(x + 2 \pi i)$ trick to rewrite one of the integral, such that it's equal to the original integral with a front fractor. And lastly isolate the original integral. It works out! Thank you